# Matching paragraphs in Go

Tags: regex, go

I'm a Go beginner. I'm trying to match paragraphs with `regexp`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := `first paragraph

second paragraph

third paragraph`

    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`(.+)(\n\n)`)

    fmt.Println(r.FindAllString(str, -1))
}
```

The output is this:

```
[first paragraph

 second paragraph

]
```

I think it's matching the empty lines also. I only want to match the paragraphs (`first paragraph`, `second paragraph`).

How to modify my code to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you need to match `third paragraph` too? Or just the first 2?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Yeah, I just realized that problem. No need for now. I'll figure out that later.

Comment: Is regex a requirement? It seems overkill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, using a [re2-compliant regexp](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax), `(?s).*?(\n\n|$)` (see [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/8XyW3kKER6)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := `first paragraph
second line of first paragraph

second paragraph

third paragraph
second line of third paragraph`

    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`(?s).*?(\n\n|$)`)

    res := r.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Printf("%+v %d", res, len(res))
}
```

That would output:

```
[first paragraph
second line of first paragraph

 second paragraph

 third paragraph
second line of third paragraph] 3
```